# XPath select node from correct level

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

I've got the following (simplified) XML...

```
<root type="object">
    <user type="object">
        <id type="number">123</id>
    </user>
    <id type="number">456</id>
</root>
```

I'm using the following to get the Id from the root element

```
    Dim Navigator = Document.CreateNavigator()
    Dim ns = New XmlNamespaceManager(Navigator.NameTable)
    Dim nodes = Navigator.Select("/root", ns)
    Dim Node = nodes.Current
    Element = Node.SelectSingleNode("/id")
    Dim Id = Element.Value
```

In this case, Element.Value contains the User Id

What's the correct selector for the root Id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you select the root-id node directly?

```
Navigator.Select("/root/id", ns)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem is here**:

```
Element = Node.SelectSingleNode("/id")
```

You have specified that an absolute expression `/id` should be evaluated.

This is an *absolute* XPath expression (starts with `/`) that selects the top element of the XML document, if its name is `"id"`. In this specific case the top element's name is `"root"` (not `"id"`), therefore the XPath expression selects nothing.

**Solution**: Either:

1. **Use a relative expression**: `Element = Node.SelectSingleNode("id")`
2. **Select the wanted element with a single XPath expression**:

.

```
    Element = Navigator.SelectSingleNode("/root", ns)
```

Comment: Thank you for the more detailed explanation. I tried both `/id` and `id` and both returned nothing. Perhaps I was starting from the wrong node ot something else equally stupid - I can't see another reason for it to fail.

Comment: @Basiclife: Perhaps `Node` isn't defined correctly. Perhaps something like: `Dim Node = Navigator.SelectSingleNode(/*)`  ?